# How to pass a variable to a function without affecting it

Tags: c#, variables, scope, console-application

i have something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] sqa = new int[2];
    sqa[0] = 1;
    sqa[1] = 2;
    func(sqa);
}

static void func(int[] sqa)
{
    sqa[0] = 0;
    sqa[1] = 1;
}
```

after i call `func()`, value change in `Main() function, too.

how can i prevent to do this and play with variables without changing them?

Comment: Remove the static keyword from your method func()

Comment: @DanielHakimi That has nothing to do with what's happening here my good man :)

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Ahh! Reacted to quickly, one of those SMH moments haha!

Comment: @DanielHakimi didn't work, i tried this before, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array in C# is a reference type, so it is always passed by reference.
You need to create a copy of input array in your `func` method:

```
static void func(int[] input)
{
    int[] sqa = (int[])input.Clone();

    sqa[0] = 0;
    sqa[1] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Array is a reference type. You can bypass this by creating a new Array and copying the values from the old Array to the new one.

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] sqa = new int[2];
    sqa[0] = 1;
    sqa[1] = 2;

    int[] sqa2 = new int[2];
    Array.Copy(sqa, sqa2, sqa.Length);

    func(sqa2);
}

static void func(int[] sqa)
{
    sqa[0] = 0;
    sqa[1] = 1;
}
```